# Is it normal to have a higher mean average precision but lower confusion matrix precision-recall in TensorFlow object detection?

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api, mscoco

I need an explanation about. It is normal to have mean average precision of 0.991 using the TensorFlow object detection evaluation tool with IoU 0.5 and metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics" in a config file. But I got 0.97 in precision and 0.96 in recall with the same IoU threshold using this [code](https://github.com/svpino/tf_object_detection_cm). If it's normal, why are these two matrices different? Or is something wrong with that code.

Note: I use 76 data in my test dataset, and every data have 28 class